# in ajax $.mobile.changePage not working

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

$.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          async: false,
          url : SerURL + "/login",

1. List item

   ```
     dataType : "json",
     contentType:"application/json",
     data:JSON.stringify(data1),
     success : function(data){
       console.log('success');
       console.log(data);
       if(data.status=="20000"){
           $.mobile.changePage($("#page2"));
       }
     }
   });
   ```

why $.mobile.changePage() can not working?

Comment: current URL:http://localhost:8080/login
changePage URL:http://localhost:8080/page2
 but ready URL:http://localhost:8080/login/#/page2
so not changePage to.

Answer (score 0):

$.mobile.changePage is deprecated as of jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 and will be removed in 1.5.0.

Try using pagecontainer widget's change() method instead:

```
$("body").pagecontainer("change", "page2", { options... });
```

I hope this helps you!